# How to show the details of the whole database in one textfield

Tags: java, netbeans

This is my code but I don't understand how to put the whole table search results in one text field.

```
private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                          
    String SearchProduct ;  
    DBConnector dbcon = new DBConnector();//connecting to DB
    dbcon.connect();//code for sql to select all from the table
    if (dbcon.isProductExists) {
        msg.showMessageDialog(this,"Search Successful","Search Status",1);
        txtSearchResults.setText()
    }
    else  {
        msg.showMessageDialog(this,"no results found","Search Status",1);
    }
}
```

Is it possible? if this isn't possible can you please suggest anything else?

Comment: **Maybe**. What's in the database?

Comment: all product details like prodID,desripition,price @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Be specific. If it's three fields you could concatenate them into one textfield. If it's fifty fields you still could, but they'd be really hard to read.

Comment: there is 4 fields , ProdID,Category,Price and Stockqty also is it possible to show multiple rows too? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) can display multiple lines.

Comment: ok thanks :) @ElliottFrisch

Comment: maybe `target_label.setText(rs.getString(0)+rs.getString(1)+...+rs.getString(n));` ?!

Comment: @user5266804 I should try that :/ i am stuck in this. Is there a way to open table from java which shows all the data items in the database?

Comment: "Details of the whole database" means a full dump of every column of every row of every table in the database. That's a *lot* of data. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: Edit :i mean table,sorry  @Andreas

Comment: @AlphaBeta - Even JTable would be a better option for achieving this.

Comment: The **complete** table might still be much more than you want to show or can handle in a client application.